# How can I move the button?

Tags: java, android, string, animation, random

I am new to animations in android. I was wondering, is there a way to keep a button moving around the screen, bouncing off the walls, until it gets clicked? I was thinking to do something like this:

```
    while(!clicked){
    //Run code to move button
        }
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             public void onClick(View v) {
    clicked = true;
        }
    );
```

And to make it random, do something like this:

```
Random r = new Random();
btnCount.animate().xBy(r.nextInt(10)+1).yBy(r.nextInt(10)+1);
```

But that doesn't work, and nothing happens. I have thoroughly searched the android docs and other stack exchange pages, but they lack in detail, which is why I have come here to get help from the professionals.

What is the best way to do this animation?

Comment: btnCount.animate().xBy(r.nextInt(10)+1).yBy(r.nextInt(10)+1); works for me and animates the button.

Comment: @noev Really?! Do you mind posting me your code...It is not working for me...?

Comment: @noev I would really appreciate it...I've been stuck on this all day now!

Comment: Well I just copied animate().xBy(r.nextInt(10)+1).yBy(r.nextInt(10)+1); and used it on my button.

Comment: @noev Hmm...Is the button just moving around randomly? Because for me, my button does nothing. :( I've been trying to solve this all day now.

Comment: @noev Wait did you do something separate to start the animation? I'm really confused. For me, btnCount *is* my button. Do I need to do something else.

Comment: I'm doing the animation on click like button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Random r = new Random();
                button.animate().xBy(500).yBy(r.nextInt(10)+1);

            }
        });

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96195/discussion-between-ruchir-baronia-and-noev).